# Como desabilitar um objeto TTimer quando clicar um botão que abre um outro formulário e habilitá-lo novamente quando o outro formulário for fechado?

Tags: delphi, timer, delphi-4

Bom dia.
Tenho um timer sendo executado em um formulário que chama vários outros.
Quando esse formulário abrir outro o timer deverá ser parado e, quando o formulário que foi aberto for fechado o timer deverá ser habilitado novamente.
Entretanto, só posso fazer isso em apenas um formulário.
Há alguma forma de fazer isso?
Chamar o onclose dos formulários fechado diretamente no formulário que abre os demais?
Estou utilizando Delphi 4.

Pensei em colocar desta forma, mas não sei onde coloco esse código para que ele seja executado a todo momento.

```
if Assigned(TForm1) then
  //Criado
else
  //Não criado
```

Seria necessário outro objeto TTimer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O timer tem a propriedade `Enabled`, só marcar como `false` e depois voltar para `true`

e no formulário principal você invoca o segunda com `showmodal`, fazendo isso o formulário de trás fica em espera ate o da frente fechar.
fica pode fazer assim:

```
timer.enabled: false;

Form2:= TForm2.Create;
Form2.Showmodal;
freeanil(fomr2);

timer.enabled := true;
```

Comment: Obrigado, Gabriel. Isso eu sei, só não sei onde coloco. Se eu colocar no botão não atende, porque teria de colocar em todos os eventos onclose dos outros formulários, entende?

Comment: eu complementei a resposta, com exemplo de codigo, mas se quer fazer o segundo formulário ter o controle pode dar problema de acesso violado, melhor o formulário que tem o timer fazer o controle. se quiser pode fazer no principal um procedure genérico que abre os formulários

Comment: Funcionou Gabriel. Muito obrigado.